# Make Tomcat 7.0 flush logs to disk?

Tags: logging, tomcat

How do I get Apache Tomcat 7.0, running as a service on Windows Server 2008, to flush its logs to disk *without* restarting the service daemon?

I did find [delay on tomcat writing to logs in windows server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/175918/delay-on-tomcat-writing-to-logs-in-windows-server-2008) but logging.properties contains no bufferSize directive at all.